# Leak at [NSRunloop run]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, instruments

I am getting leaks at

```
NSRunLoop* rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
self.networkStream.delegate = self;
[self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:rl forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.networkStream open];

@autoreleasepool {
    [rl run];
}`
```

The instrument shows leak at location `[self.networkStream open]` and `[r1 run]`.

Anyone knows what may be the reason for that? Basically I am trying to use the simpleFTP example of the Apple to upload data to server... This functionality should run in the background so I have to use the [NSRunLoop run] function to keep thread alive until the request is not complete.

here is the stack trace from instruments

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib malloc_zone_malloc
1 CoreFoundation __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate
2 CoreFoundation CFAllocatorAllocate
3 CoreFoundation _CFRuntimeCreateInstance
4 CFNetwork CFObject::Allocate(unsigned long, CFClass const&, __CFAllocator const*)
5 CFNetwork CoreReadStreamCreate(__CFAllocator const*, LegacyReadStreamCallBacks const*, void*)
6 CFNetwork CoreReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(__CFAllocator const*, __CFURL const*)
7 CFNetwork CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL
8 CFTMClient -[FTPDownloadRequest startRecieving]   /Users/canv/Documents/abc/FTPDownloadRequest.m:96
9 CFTMClient -[CFTMFTPDownload sendFTPDownloadRequest] /Users/canv/Documents/Cabc/CFTMFTPDownload.m:99
10 CFTMClient -[CFTMFTPDownload startTest] /Users/canv/Documents/abc/CFTMFTPDownload.m:52
11 CFTMClient __39-[CFTMTestManager executeTestCaseList:]_block_invoke /Users/canv/Documents/abc/CFTMTestManager.m:325
12 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
14 libdispatch.dylib dispatch_barrier_sync_f
15 libdispatch.dylib dispatch_sync
16 CFTMClient -[CFTMTestManager executeTestCaseList:] /Users/canv/Documents/abc/CFTMTestManager.m:280
17 CFTMClient __35-[CFTMTestManager executeTestList:]_block_invoke /Users/canv/Documents/abc/CFTMTestManager.m:193
18 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release
19 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout
20 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_root_queue_drain
21 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_worker_thread2
22 libsystem_c.dylib _pthread_wqthread
23 libsystem_c.dylib start_wqthread
```

Comment: is this called multiple times?

Comment: Probably [run] is leaking somewhere inside. Btw. all code should be inside @autorelease not only [ run] if you want to release NSRunLoop as well within that pool

Comment: already tried that as well but still it shows leaks at same location. it doesn't matters whether i put a @autoreleas or not it always shows a leak.

Comment: What thread is this running on? If this is on the main thread, you should not call `[rl run]`, but instead just let the function return and the runloop take over naturally.

Comment: @Neal it runs in a background thread so i have to use the dispatch_queues for that I already mentioned the same that i am running it in backgraound thread.

Comment: My guess is that you have some code lacking an autorelease pool.  IIRC, the run loop itself doesn't provide one.